# Ford Radio Code

Tags: ford, audio, code

I have a C series 6000 CD in a 2006 Ford Fiesta originally sold in the Netherlands.  None of the online radio code finder services have worked.  Please provide the code so I can unlock my stereo.  The numbers it displays is: C 040038 SA 811000.

VIN is wfodxxgajd9k26934

Can you please give me the correct code?

Thank you.

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone on here can help you with that, as we don't have access to anything more than the same online services - if they don't work your best bet is to contact Ford directly.

Answer (score 0):

Now this is a code bypass that worked on the X type Jaguars up till 2006 or so (when Ford owned Jag...), so be warned it may not work for you... Do try your dealer first... Some can be very helpful.

However, it did work for my 2005 x type, so you never know:

Enter any code 3 times so that the display shows "PLEASE WAIT"

Simultaneously press ">>" "PTY" "A.MEM" should only take 2 or 3 seconds and the radio turns on.