# Radio code for Ford focus 2006

Tags: audio

I had a new battery fitted in my car and I now need the radio code I was wondering if anyone knew where I could get the code for free?

It's a Ford focus 2006 and the radio serial number is M068728

Thank you

Comment: See my answer here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/66864/10976 if it helps give it a vote...

Comment: The serial numbers starting with M like yours are FREE to get the code for. DO NOT PAY.

Comment: Thank you for the question. It's still relevant

Answer (score 0):

You can go onto https://www.carradiodecoder.com/2012/01/ and it should help you with your findings. The Ford radio code video should be there for you to get your answer. However: This may take some time and do not be worried if your radio code does not come in for about a week or two. I did it with my Mercedes and it took about a month to getback the results.
Welcome to the Community!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I believe the reason for the downvote is the link you provided looks like spam. Basically, you're pushing users out to a different website from here, which isn't quite kosher. If it's the only way you can present your information, then please state your affiliation with the linked website.